# Is it possible to fetch the annotation of the tags only from a remote repository?

Tags: git

I'm using git tags for some dev ops thus the question:

Is it possible to download the annotated message of the tags only using git or lower level utils(i.e. upload/fetch pack) or the protocol itself?

Some of the "solutions" I've found that don't fit the bill:

- `git fetch --tags`
- `git clone --branch <tag> --single-branch`
- `git clone with --depth=<depth>`

All these download quite a lot of data that I don't need.
I need only the tag annotation/ message. The ideal solution should allow fetching the tag messages with minimal bandwidth overhead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to download the annotated message of the tags only

Nope.

You can download **all** the repository data or a given commit (commit also means tag or branch) but you cant fetch any partial data unless its a part of the commit tree.

You must checkout from the latest commit back but you cant fetch commits with gaps between them.

Tag is simply a reference to a commit, you can fetch it all and display the message once the code is on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin access to the other repo you can set it up with a pre-receive exit that runs a for-each-ref in response to pushing refs you reserve for this. The simplest would be something like

```
#!/bin/sh
rc=0
while read old new ref; do
        if [[ $ref = refs/requests/refcontents ]]; then
                git for-each-ref --format='%(refname) %(objectname)

%(contents)
-------- '
        rc=1
        fi
done
exit $rc
```

Remember you can push to any repo, so to test that you can drop it in `.git/hooks/pre-receive`, `chmod +x` it, and `git push . @:refs/requests/refcontents`.